# Vorticity - Rankine vortex: how can we say that $\frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z} = 0$

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation, vortex

\subsection{a}
A Vortex formed in a bathtub, tornado or in other real world scenarios, exhibit nearly a solid body rotation in the core while far away from the center the flow is irrotational. This behavior is idealized in the so called Rankine vortex. The velocities are given (in polar coordinates) by
\textbf{answer}:
for 
$$
\textbf{u}= \begin{bmatrix}
u_r \\
u_{\phi} \\
u_z
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
u_{\phi} \\
0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
u_{\phi} =
\begin{cases}
\Omega r & \mbox{if } r < R \quad \text{Rotational part}
\\
R^2 \Omega/r & \mbox{if } r > R  \quad \text{Irrotational part}
\end{cases}
$$
Where $\Omega$ is the angular velocity of the solid body rotation

Calculate the vorticity $\omega = \nabla × u$. Hint: You can use a cylindrical or a polar coordinate system, but keep in mind that also the $\nabla$-operator has to be expressed in the given coordinate system, i.e.
$$
\nabla_{(x,y,z)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\\[0.3cm]
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\\[0.3cm]
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \nabla_{(x,y,z)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\\[0.3cm]
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi}\\[0.3cm]
\frac{\partial }{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
Using the definition of Curl in the cylindrical system

\begin{align}
 \omega =\text{Curl }\vec{V}(x,y,z) &= 
 \nabla \times \textbf{u} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\[0.3cm]
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\\[0.3cm]
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}
 \times
 \begin{bmatrix}
  u_r \\
  u_{\phi} \\
  u_z
 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\[0.3cm]
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\\[0.3cm]
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}
 \times
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  u_{\phi} \\
  0
 \end{bmatrix} \\
 &= 
 \det \begin{pmatrix}
  \hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  u_r & u_{\phi} & u_z
 \end{pmatrix}\\
 &= \hat{\imath}\big(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial u_{\phi}} - \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z}\big)
 -
 \hat{\jmath}\big(\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z}\big)
 +
 \hat{k}\big(\frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \phi}\big) \\
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial u_{\phi}} - \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \phi}
 \end{bmatrix}\\ 
&= \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial u_{\phi}} - \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} \\[0.2cm]
  \frac{1}{r}\big(
  \frac{\partial r u_{\phi}}{\partial r} -\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \phi}\big)
 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{how can we mathematically assert that } \frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r u_{\phi}}{\partial r}\text{?}\\
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
  0 - 0\\
  0 - 0 \\
  \frac{1}{r}
  \frac{\partial r u_{\phi}}{\partial r}-0
 \end{bmatrix}\quad \textbf{question: how can we say that } \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z} = 0
\end{align}

it is given that
\begin{equation}
 u_{\phi} =
 \begin{cases}
  \Omega r & \mbox{if } r < R \quad \text{Rotational part}
  \\
  R^2 \Omega/r & \mbox{if } r > R  \quad \text{Irrotational part}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
hence

\begin{equation}
 \omega_{r, \phi, z} =
 \begin{cases}
  \Omega 2 & \mbox{if } r < R \quad \text{Rotational part}
  \\
  0 & \mbox{if } r > R\quad \text{Irrotational part}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here is my questions:

- **how can we say that** $\frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial z} = 0$ in the calculation of the vorticity??
- how can we mathematically assert that $\frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r u_{\phi}}{\partial r}$

Comment: But you give a formula for $u_\phi$ at the top of your post and it doesn't depend on $z$.

Comment: many thanks @jacob1729. You're right. I have another question: how can we mathematically assert that $\frac{\partial u_{\phi}}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r u_{\phi}}{\partial r}$?

Comment: I'm very dubious about the way you've taken a curl here. Certainly it is not true that $\partial_r (u_\phi) = 1/r \partial_r (r u_\phi)$ as can be see by simply expanding the RHS. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) for example on how to deal with different co-ordinate systems.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments @jacob1729. It helped a lot!